# Read lines from txt that share a common element?

Tags: python

If I had a file called 'names.txt' that contained the following:

```
Adam Jones
Mary Smith
Matt Good
Huey Lee
Matt Armstrong
```

How do I only print the lines with 'Matt' (without using line number)?

Comment: what you try before ?

Comment: Try to post some approach of you in your questions as well...

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("names.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("Matt"):
            print line.strip()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("names.txt") as txt:
    [line for line in txt.readlines() if "Matt" in line]
```

But this will return `list` of lines with Matt

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
with open("names.txt") as names:
for row in names:
    if row.startswith("Matt"):
        print(row.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

using `find`:

```
f=open('file.txt')
for x in f:
    if x.find('Matt')>=0:
        print(x)
```